# Symfony form widget custom rendering

Tags: symfony1, symfony-forms

I am looking for a way to automate a form output to json format instead of html.
I am using JQuery dform http://plugins.jquery.com/project/dform to create dynamic forms.

Sample output:

> {
>               "type" : "p",
>               "html" : "You must login"
>           },
>           {
>               "name" : "username",
>               "id" : "txt-username",
>               "caption" : "Username",
>               "type" : "text",
>               "placeholder" : "E.g. user@example.com"
>           },
>           {
>               "name" : "password",
>               "caption" : "Password",
>               "type" : "password"
>           },
>           {
>               "type" : "submit",
>               "value" : "Login"
>           }

Please help

Answer (score 3):

Create a `renderJSON` method and attach it to `BaseForm`. The method would iterate through the the `sfFormFields` and build an array that you could then pass to `json_encode`.

An ideal solution  would be to inject your own class into the `sfWidgetForm` inheritance chain with a `renderJSON` method so that individual widgets can control their JSON format. Unfortunately, Symfony makes this very difficult to do.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by attach it to BaseForm, you mean rewrite the symfony file?

Comment: No, the Symfony `sfForm` inheritance chain contains a `BaseForm` class that is yours to add methods to.

Comment: He means BaseForm in `lib/form/BaseForm.class.php`.

Comment: but every widget has its own render, how do you add JsonRender without touching the Widget classes?